# How can I expose part of a page in response to a button click

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

I want a simple way in Visualforce to expose part of the page in response to a button click.  This should be easy, but it is giving me more trouble than anything I've done with VF to date.

After reading [How can an apex:pageBlockSection be rerendered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-can-an-apexpageblocksection-be-rerendered-if-it-originally-has-a-render-val) I wrapped the re-render section in a div tag, but that didn't help at all.

Here is a much-simplified version of the page:

```
<apex:page controller="ProvisioningController">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!showActivationForm}" value="Activate" rerender="activationForm"/> 
    </apex:form>

    <div id="activationForm">
        <apex:form rendered="{!activationFormIsVisible}">
            <p>Show some more fields here...</p>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!updateDb}" value="Whatever, Man"/>
        </apex:form>
    </div>

</apex:page>
```

And the relevant controller code:

```
public with sharing class ProvisioningController {

    public Boolean activationFormIsVisible { get; private set; }

    public ProvisioningController() {
        activationFormIsVisible = false;
    }

    public PageReference showActivationForm() {
        this.activationFormIsVisible = true;
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }
}
```

It seems like I shouldn't even need to use my controller for this kind of task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you can only `rerender` Visualforce components -- the Visualforce framework can't tell that you have a plain HTML `<div>`.  This should work:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="activationForm">
    <apex:form rendered="{!activationFormIsVisible}">
        <p>Show some more fields here...</p>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!updateDb}" value="Whatever, Man"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Having said that, I think you're right, and this is total overkill.  It's one of the places where plain Javascript/jQuery shines:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="jQuery('#activationForm').slideDown()">
    Activate
</button>

<div id="activationForm" style="display:none">
    <apex:form rendered="{!activationFormIsVisible}">
        <p>Show some more fields here...</p>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!updateDb}" value="Whatever, Man"/>
    </apex:form>
</div>
```

Here, the `btn` style on the `<button>` lets you mimic SFDC's standard button styling (if you want), and the `style` attribute on the div keeps it hidden when the page is first loaded.