# Can't use selected picklist value to render a outputpanel

Tags: visualforce

I have a dynamically generated picklist, which generates fine below:

```
> public string ConNames {get;set;} 
> List<SelectOption> options = new
> List<SelectOption>(); Public list<SelectOption> getAccCons(){
>     system.debug('>>> Generating contact list');
>     List<Contact> conList = New List<Contact>();
>     conList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :AccId];
>     options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--')); 
>     For (Contact con : ConList){
>         options.add(new SelectOption(con.Id,con.Name)); 
>         options.add(new SelectOption('Create New Contact','Create New Contact'));            
>     }
>     return options;}
```

Which is used in a VF page as below:

```
    <apex:selectList value="{!ConNames}" size="1" label="Select Contact">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccCons}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="test"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

If the select value = 'Create New Contact' I wanted to rerender the outputpanel 'Test'. I'm currently trying to use:

> rendered="{!ConNames = 'Create New Contact'}">

But this is always returning false as ConNames is always null, what am I missing? I can see the rerender is working.

Comment: Girbot - a) Have you checked out http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html which addresses a common rerender issue?  and b) best practice would be to name the value= attribute on selectList as a singular since this select List is not a multiselect. I tend to use variable like `selectedContactId` in situations like this.

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks both points are helpful! I've got it sorted now and added an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an apex:pageBlockSection be rerendered if it originally has a render value of false?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-can-an-apexpageblocksection-be-rerendered-if-it-originally-has-a-render-val)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working it appears I was hitting the same issue as in this answer by LaceySnr: [How can an apex:pageBlockSection be rerendered if it originally has a render value of false?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-can-an-apexpageblocksection-be-rerendered-if-it-originally-has-a-render-val)

I started my page again from scratch and gradually rebuilt it, the issue was to do with how I had used the `<apex:pageBlockSections>`

Answer (score 0):

Use VF Page function

```
ISPICKVAL : Determines if the value of a picklist field is equal to a text literal you specify.
```

Refer this [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)

If in case you get some save error, please check this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/errors-using-ispickval-on-visualforce-page) for workaround or use == for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't clear in my question - ConNames is always null at the moment so the render part isn't the issue yet. I've updated my question to be clearer.

Comment: @Girbot Can you please post the further code including outputpanel too.

Answer (score 0):

{!ConNames = 'Create New Contact''}
You are having single quote twice. Try fixing that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry typo in the post I've updated it. The issue is that ConNames is always null, so at the moment the render attribute isn't the issue. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: ConNames where are you geting it? it is supposed  to be null